# How to return specific data from php to jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my js file i am sending array of data to my php file and i want to print name in #NAME and password in #PASSWORD but i am getting both values name and password in #NAME and #PASSWORD, its something like this:

[image]

how i want it to print:

[image]

```js
$("#name").keyup(function() {
  var form = $("#form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: form,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#NAME").html(data);
    }
  });
});

$("#password").keyup(function() {
  var form = $("#form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: form,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#PASSWORD").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">

    Name :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><span id="NAME">I want name here from index.php, but it returns both name and password</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>Password :
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><span id="PASSWORD">I want password here from index.php, but it returns both</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    is there any other way of doing it in the same index.php file?

  </form>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending the same form for both calls it would be easier to wrap it up into 1 call and handle both instances and return the data via an array.

PHP

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "John Doe";
$arr[1] = "password";

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: form,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#NAME").html(data[0]);
    $("#PASSWORD").html(data[1]);
  }
});
```

Note that you should make sure to include the dataType in your `$.ajax` call so that jQuery knows how to parse the response.